# while no me trae todos los resulados de una tabla

Tags: sql-server

en una pregunta anterior había planteado este código, hizo lo que yo nocesitaba que hiciera, pero haciendo unas pequeñas revisiones me di cuenta que no me está trayendo todas las filas que necesito:

```
use STIPS_OLD
go

    CREATE TABLE #idx_temp
    (
id int  ,
Table_Name varchar (120),
Index_Name varchar (120),
Index_type varchar (120),
Fragmentation_Percentage float
    )

insert into #idx_temp 
    SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(IDX.OBJECT_ID)  AS Table_Name , 
IDX.name AS Index_Name, 
IDXPS.index_type_desc AS Index_Type, 
IDXPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent  Fragmentation_Percentage
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) IDXPS 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes IDX  ON IDX.object_id = IDXPS.object_id 
AND IDX.index_id = IDXPS.index_id 
where avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 60 and IDX.name is not null 
ORDER BY Fragmentation_Percentage

/*****************|declaración de variables|********************/  
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
declare @counter int
declare  @id_tmp2 int
declare @tabla_nom varchar(120)
declare @idx_nom varchar(120)

set @counter=0

/***************************************************************/
CREATE TABLE #idx_tmp_locator
(
id int,
Index_Name varchar (120),
Table_Name varchar (120)

)


/***************************************************************/

while exists (select top 1 Table_Name,Index_Name ,Index_type,Fragmentation_Percentage  from #idx_temp )
begin
--set @counter = @counter + 1
--select @counter as contador
select top 1  @idx_nom =Index_Name ,@tabla_nom =Table_Name , @id_tmp2= id from #idx_temp 

insert into #idx_tmp_locator values(@id_tmp2,@tabla_nom,@idx_nom)



set @sql='
ALTER INDEX '+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +' ' +@idx_nom+ '   ON   ' +@tabla_nom+ ''+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' REORGANIZE WITH( LOB_COMPACTION = ON );'
+ CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '
UPDATE STATISTICS  '+@tabla_nom+'  '+@idx_nom +'
'
--exec sp_executesql @sql
select @sql as sql_qr

delete from #idx_temp  where Index_Name=@idx_nom and Table_Name = @tabla_nom

end

--drop table #idx_temp

--create table #tmp_2_idx
--(
--id int,
--Table_Name varchar (120),
--Index_Name varchar (120),
--Index_type varchar (120),
--Fragmentation_Percentage float
--)

insert into #tmp_2_idx
select * from #idx_temp

insert into #idx_temp
select * from  #tmp_2_idx 

--drop table #idx_tmp_locator

select itl.id,   itl.Index_Name,t2i.table_name from #idx_tmp_locator itl
right join #tmp_2_idx t2i

on  itl.id = t2i.id
order by t2i.id
```

he creado la tabla `#tmp_2_idx` debido a que la consulta que me inserta los datos de los indices se demora un poco en la ejecución, por lo tanto creé esa tabla temporal para almacenar dichos datos, ya que la tabla `#idx_temp` borra cada fila en el while

la pregunta es: ¿donde se encuentran los datos que me faltan?

cabe resaltar que a las tablas les puse `id's`
para dar solución a ese problema pero en realidad lo que necesito saber es porque me faltan esos registros sin los id

adjunto el resultado de la consulta

```
select itl.id,   itl.Index_Name,t2i.table_name from #idx_tmp_locator itl
right join #tmp_2_idx t2i

on  itl.id = t2i.id
order by t2i.id

/*************************************************/
id  Index_Name  table_name
1   horario horario
2   horario horario
3   horario horario
4   horario horario
5   horario horario
6   horario horario
7   tpHELogoxIPS    tpHELogoxIPS
8   TR_AgnEspecialidadEmpresa   TR_AgnEspecialidadEmpresa
9   TM_DetalleLog   TM_DetalleLog
10  settings    settings
11  horario_OLD horario_OLD
12  horario_OLD horario_OLD
13  horario_OLD horario_OLD
14  medicos medicos
15  AUDI_OPERACIONCITA  AUDI_OPERACIONCITA
16  medicos medicos
17  TM_ServiciosAutorizacion    TM_ServiciosAutorizacion
18  medicos medicos
19  medicos medicos
20  medicos medicos
21  medicos medicos
22  horario horario
23  horario horario
24  horario horario
25  TM_GeneracionAutorizacion   TM_GeneracionAutorizacion
26  TM_GeneracionAutorizacion   TM_GeneracionAutorizacion
27  TM_GeneracionAutorizacion   TM_GeneracionAutorizacion
28  medicos medicos
29  horario horario
30  horario horario
31  horario horario
32  TM_GeneracionAutorizacion   TM_GeneracionAutorizacion
33  TM_Log  TM_Log
34  TM_ServiciosAutorizacion    TM_ServiciosAutorizacion
35  Detconsultas    Detconsultas
36  TaAgAuditarCondonacion  TaAgAuditarCondonacion
37  horario horario
38  horario horario
39  horario horario
40  horario horario
41  horario horario
42  horario horario
43  horario horario
44  horario horario
NULL    NULL    horario
46  horario horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
NULL    NULL    horario
```

de antemano agradezco toda la información brindada

Comment: ¿Borraste la propierdad identity de tu tabla #idx_temp? De otra forma, el código no podría ejecutarse como lo tienes.

Comment: si, si la borré pero para poder almacenar los datos a otro tabla pero si requiere identity ahi

Answer (score 0):

El código tal como lo tienes no se podría ejecutar. También es muy raro que tengas tantos nombres de tablas e índices repetidos. El código se puede simplificar para tenerlo en una sola instrucción y se le puede agregar un GROUP BY para evitar duplicados causados por particiones. También agregué la capacidad de usar schemas para evitar problemas por ello.

```
CREATE TABLE #idx_tmp_locator(
    id int, 
    Index_Name  sysname, 
    Table_Name  sysname,
    Schema_Name sysname
);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @SQL += N'
     INSERT INTO #idx_tmp_locator (Index_Name, Table_Name, Schema_Name)
     VALUES(' + QUOTENAME(IDX.name, '''') + N', ' + QUOTENAME(O.name, '''')  + N', ' + QUOTENAME(S.name, '''') + N');

     ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME( IDX.name) + N' ON '+ QUOTENAME( S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME( O.name) + N'
      REORGANIZE WITH( LOB_COMPACTION = ON );

     UPDATE STATISTICS  ' + QUOTENAME( S.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME( O.name) + N'  ' + QUOTENAME( IDX.name) + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
FROM   sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS IDXPS
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS IDX ON IDX.object_id = IDXPS.object_id
                                 AND IDX.index_id = IDXPS.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O ON O.object_id = IDX.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
WHERE IDXPS.index_type_desc <> 'HEAP'
AND   IDXPS.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 60
GROUP BY S.name, O.name, IDX.name;

--exec sp_executesql @sql;
SELECT @sql AS sql_qr;

GO
```